# Audio Jack unplug event

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

Is there an event signifying an audio jack plug or unplug on an android device in a web browser I can use? I can't seem to find one other than native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears as though there is no way to do this specifically for the jack. But pulling out the jack does call the "pause" event on the audio element. So I was able to use this to determine what to do with any looping audio.

```
    if( loop ) {
        audio.removeEventListener( "pause", onAudioFail );
        audio.addEventListener( "pause", onAudioFail ); //This is to handle the audio jack unplug issue
    }
    audio.play();
    return;
}
```